# Magento 2 - Order email - template override not working

Tags: magento2, orders, email-templates, order-email

I need to style the items table in the order email.

So I have copied

> /vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/

to

> /app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Sales/templates/email/

Added some content, ran my script that fixes most of the "issues"

```
rm -R ./pub/static/*
./php bin/magento cache:clean
./php bin/magento cache:flush
./php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --force
./php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy sk_SK --force
./php bin/magento setup:di:compile
./php bin/magento indexer:reindex
./php bin/magento cache:clean
chown zonemediadev.sk:html ./ -R
```

note: ./php is shortcut to php7 because the server by default has php5 on cli.

I have re-sent the order email from admin, then manually triggered cron. Then I have received the email without the added content.

If I add content in the /vendor/....../templates/email/items.phtml then it works fine.

Also I am receiving the same email multiple times (from 2 times up to 11 times) Why?

**Any suggestions why the override does not work?**

Comment: really strange ...

Comment: You can override email templates from **`Marketing -> Communications (Email Templates)`** and then by clicking on **`Add New Template`** button.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Already did that, that overrides header, footer, body text and the layout, which works. But to customize the html of the table of product in email body it's required to change the Magento_Sales/templates/email/items.phtml  and magento does not detect the override, since its still loading from /vendor/magento/..../...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, on the next day it started working. Probably some buggy background cache.